# subquery returns more than 1 value this is not permitted when the subquery follows

Tags: mysql

I don't know why my case code is having an error but when I execute it not using a parameter by replacing the `@PersonId by 2` it runs well. I try to exchange2x the `JOIN` but I am still having an error. Anyone knows?.

```
case    when ISNULL(dbo.EducationalBackground.SchoolId,'') = '' then
                (Select a.SchoolName 
                    from dbo.EducationalBackground as A INNER JOIN
                        dbo.PersonEducationalBackground as B on a.EducationalBackgroundId = b.EducationalBackgroundId  INNER JOIN
                        dbo.EducationLevel as C on a.EducationalLevelId = c.EducationLevelId 
                        where b.PersonId = @PersonId and a.EducationalLevelId in (2,3))

       else (select dbo.school.SchooldName from dbo.School INNER JOIN dbo.EducationalBackground
            ON dbo.School.SchoolId = dbo.EducationalBackground.SchoolId INNER JOIN
            dbo.PersonEducationalBackground ON dbo.EducationalBackground.EducationalBackgroundId = dbo.PersonEducationalBackground.EducationalBackgroundId
            where dbo.PersonEducationalBackground.PersonId = @PersonId)
```

Cheers. Thanks.

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory: Your subquery (may) return more than one record, and MySQL is expecting a scalar (single value).  A brute-force fix might be to use `LIMIT 1` on the subquery, but a better fix would be to update your logic so that this doesn't happen.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Its okay now. I thought that the value(3) from 1 table may ok because of the condition that i created.